# Python's enumerate in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, enumerate

```
def enumerate(arr):
    (0..arr.length - 1).to_a.zip(arr)
```

Is something built in for this? It doesn't need to have it's members immutable, it just needs to be in the standard library. I don't want to be the guy who subclasses the Array class to add a Python feature to a project.

Does it have a different name in Ruby?

```
%w(a b c).enumerate
=> [[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"], [3, "d"]]
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like this in Python:

```
a = ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa']
for i, s in enumerate(a):
    print('%s at index %d' % (s, i))
```

becomes this in Ruby:

```
a = %w(do re mi fa)
a.each_with_index do |s,i|
    puts "#{s} at index #{i}"
end
```

Comment: `a = 'do re mi fa'.split()` might be closer to the Ruby version

Answer (score 8):

Assuming it's for enumeration, [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) can do that. Or if you have an `Enumerator`, just use [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a quicker solution would be :

```
%w(a b c).map.with_index {|x, i| [i, x] }
```

Comment: Hey...that looks more familiar `;)`.

Answer (score 2):

A fun one!

```
a = %w(do re mi fa)
a.length.times.zip a
```

Comment: In python, this would be `zip(range(len(a)), a)` just in case you're like me and had to run `irb` to catch on to this clever use of `.times`. Very nice